# Is this Riccati ODE solvable? If so, how may I guess the particular solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on a problem and came across this Riccati(?) ODE. Is this solvable? Or must I have two other ODEs for $a(t)$ and $\theta (t)$?

$m'(t) = - c_1 \frac{m^2 (t)}{a(t)}\cos(\theta (t) ) - c_2 \theta (t) m(t)$

In general, does there exist a more concrete way of 'guessing' a particular solution to a Riccati ODE such that you may make the transformation

$z=\frac{1}{y-y_0}$,

where $y_0$ is the particular solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Riccati ODE is solvable. The analytic solution is :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! How did you come up with the substitution for m(t) (your third line)?

Comment: It is a classical change of function : Eq.(5) in  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiccatiDifferentialEquation.html